# Docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a bare bones postgres container that I can launch no problem using:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/ec2-user/secrets:/mnt/secrets -v demo-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data demo-postgres
```

How do I get to an interactive psql prompt such that i can create a db, add table, values, ect?

Answer (score 0):

I usually separate `run`ning container in detached mode and `exec`ing into it using psql:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your_password --name pgl postgres:latest
docker exec -it -u postgres pgl psql
```